# How to translate numbers to binary for assembly

Tags: java, assembly, binary, numbers

Could someone give me guidance on how to translate numbers into their binary equivalent from an instruction for an assembler? The numbers can range from 0 to 255 and need to be 8 bits long.

Here is my method that performs the translation from instructions to their binary equivalent

````
```
public void translateInstruction(String instruction) {
        String[] parts = instruction.split("[\\s,]+");
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

        if (parts.length > 0) {
            switch (parts[0]) {
                case "LOADN":
                    output.print("1111");
                   break;
                case "LOADA":
                output.print("1110");
                break;
                case "ADD":
                output.print("1101");
                break;
                case "SUB":
                output.print("1100");
                break;
                case "JMP":
                output.print("1011");
                break;
                case "COPY":
                output.print("1000");
                break;
                case "STORE":
                output.print("1001");
                break;
             
           }
        }

        if (parts.length > 1) {
            switch (parts[1]) {
                case "A":
                   output.print("01");
                    break;
                case "D":
                    output.print("10");
                    break;
                
            }
        } else {
             output.print("00");
        }

          if (parts.length > 2) {
             switch (parts[2]) {
                case "A":
                     output.print("01");
                    break;
               case "D":
                   output.print("10");
                   break;
             
           }
       } else {
             output.print("00");
        }

        output.println();
        if (parts.length > 3) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
            String binary = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(number)).replace(' ', '0');
            output.println(binary);
        }
   }
```
````

Comment: If there aren't that many different formats (numbers of operands and allowed positions of immediates), you could just support 3 different ones and dispatch according to the instruction mnemonic.  You already have a `switch` on the mnemonics, so you could set a variable to one of three values. (Does Java have `enum`?  That would be appropriate.)

Comment: That code is specifically only looking for constants in the 4th or greater argument position, so if you want something different then change the code.  One way is to set a flag or marker based on the opcode, while another is to finish parsing the line customized for each opcode, both of these use information about the opcode to allow/disallow further argument counts and kinds.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question; the original question has an answer that might be useful to future readers, which Erik spent some effort writing.  (And it has your code which might also be useful to some future readers, and which is necessary context for the answer.)  If you have a different question, post a new question.  (But the final form after your edit, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77636723/3 , is not a useful question. Don't post that.  Nobody knows what you mean because you didn't show an example of the input and output you wanted to handle.

Comment: This still looks like a different question than the one Erik's answer was answering.  Post a new question (you can include a link to this one to let people know it's a follow-up).  Also, it's still not exactly clear what you want the output to look like.  The whole instruction has to be 8 bits long, so you need to limit the range of immediate operands?  And the output is actually still a string of ASCII base-2 digits, not binary bytes?

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, that code is throwing away valuable information.  After going to the work to determine the opcode, that determination is used solely to emit the opcode itself, but is not being used to inform how to handle the operands.

Typically, an instruction set architecture has ***formats*** and each format has certain number and kind of operands that are allowed — each instruction will take the shape of one of the formats.

So, what you can do is:

- set a variable that indicates the format for that opcode, then handle the formats:

```
    if ( opcode == "ADD" ) { emit ( "0000" ); format = Three_operand; } break;
    ...
    switch ( format ) {
    case Three_operand: ... break;
    }
```

- handle each opcode to completion within your larger opcode detection statement:

```
    if ( opcode == "ADD" ) { emit ( "0000" ); handle3operands (); } break;

    // nothing left to do here as common code is invoked by function call.
```